# In scala 2.13+ / 3.x, how can we address the diamond inheritance problem of abstract types?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type, abstract-type

Here is a simple example:

```scala
trait Sup {

  type A

  def a: A

  def b: A
}

trait Sub1 extends Sup {

  override type A = Product

  override def a = "s" -> "s"
}

trait Sub2 extends Sup {

  override type A = Serializable

  override def b = "s" -> "s"
}

object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2
```

Obviously it will cause a compilation error, as both `override type A` are mutually exclusive. This is counter-intuitive as Product & Serializable are commonly used together. Alternatively, I can define:

```scala
trait Sup {

  type A

  def a: A
}

trait Sub1 extends Sup {

  override type A <: Product

  override def a = "s" -> "s"
}

trait Sub2 extends Sup {

  override type A <: Serializable

  override def b = "s" -> "s"
}

object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 {

  override type A = Product with Serializable
}
```

This makes definition of a and b invalid, as type A hasn't been reified, in addition, the line `override type A = Product with Serializable` is clearly a boilerplate and can be inferred instead.

What is the correct way to define an abstract type that allows diamond mixin, while avoid the boilerplate to explicitly define it in every implementations?

Comment: `override type A = Product with Serializable` is not a boilerplate (it can't be inferred). One could define `object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 { case class MyClass(i: Int); override type A = MyClass; override def a = MyClass(1) }`. `MyClass` is a different type from `Product with Serializable`. You have to specify what type you mean in object `SS`.

Comment: What could probably be inferred is `object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 { override type A <: Product with Serializable }` (without `def a`). Well, Scala chose to be more explicit here.

Comment: In your case MyClass <: Product with Serializable so it is a narrowing that is optional.
But you are right, boilerplate is not an important issue, so I change my example to something more serious (justifiable but cannot compile)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you lost lower bounds.

`"s" -> "s"` has type `(String, String)`, which is a subtype of `Product` (and `Serializable`) but not a subtype of `A <: Product` (or `A <: Serializable`).

Try

```
trait Sup {
  type A
  def a: A
  def b: A
}

trait Sub1 extends Sup {
  override type A >: (String, String) <: Product
  override def a = "s" -> "s"
}

trait Sub2 extends Sup {
  override type A >: (String, String) <: Serializable
  override def b = "s" -> "s"
}

object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 {
  override type A = Product with Serializable
}

SS.a: (String, String)
SS.b: (String, String)
implicitly[SS.A =:= (Product with Serializable)]
```

If you specify return type of `Sub1#a`, `Sub2#b` to be `A` (above they were inferred to be `(String, String)` i.e. return type was narrowed upon method overriding) then

```
trait Sup {
  type A
  def a: A
  def b: A
}

trait Sub1 extends Sup {
  override type A >: (String, String) <: Product
  override def a: A = "s" -> "s"
}

trait Sub2 extends Sup {
  override type A >: (String, String) <: Serializable
  override def b: A = "s" -> "s"
}

object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 {
  override type A = Product with Serializable
}

SS.a: Product with Serializable
SS.b: Product with Serializable
implicitly[SS.A =:= (Product with Serializable)]
```

You can do even

```
object SS extends Sub1 with Sub2 {
  override type A >: (String, String) <: Product with Serializable
}
```